# Invalid workflow file Github Actions (CF CLI)

Tags: github, command-line-interface, github-actions, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to get this github action to work but once committed it gives me this error:

> Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/main.yml#L1
> No steps defined in `steps` and no workflow called in `uses` for the following jobs: build

Anyone have any idea what this might depend on?

Below is the code I used:

```
  name: Deploy to Cloud Foundry

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    # Build your app here

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    needs: build
    
    steps:
    - uses: citizen-of-planet-earth/cf-cli-action@master
      with:
        cf_api: https://api.my-cloud-foundry.com
        cf_username: ${{ secrets.CF_USER }}
        cf_password: ${{ secrets.CF_PASSWORD }}
        cf_org: AwesomeApp
        cf_space: Development
        command: push -f manifest-dev.yml
```

Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: the job named `build` should contains some `steps` inside

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Workflow Syntax for Github Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions), you'll identify that some fields are mandatory.

At the workflow level, you need to have at least a trigger (configure with the `on` field) and a list of `jobs` specified.

Then, in that list of `jobs`, you have to specify at least one job, where each of those jobs needs at least the `runner` and the `steps` (or the `uses` for reusable workflow) field configured.

**Example of the minimum configurations you would use for a job:**

```yaml
on: push

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print a greeting
        run: echo 'Hello World'

  job2: # reusable workflow scenario
    uses: owner/repo/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@main
```